# Non decreasing array logic fail

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the non decreasing array problem

Given an array nums with n integers, check if it could become non-decreasing by modifying at most one element.

Non-decreasing is defined as follows: if nums[i] <= nums[i + 1] holds for every i (0-based) such that (0 <= i <= n - 2).

Here is my solution that works for [4,2,3] but does not for [-1,4,2,3]

According to my logic when the pointer is at 2 for [-1,4,2,3],the if block will be executed at i-2(-1) is less than i(2) and the value of 4 will chnage to 2 but apparently that does not happen.

```
#nums=[4,2,3]
nums=[-1,4,2,3]
count=0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] < nums[i-1]:
        if (i==1 or nums[i-2]<=nums[i]):
            nums[i-1]=nums[i]
            count+=1
        else:
            nums[i]=nums[i-1]
            count+=1
            
print(count<=1)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont change `nums` inside the loop. you are iterating a variable and changing it inside the itertion. dont do that. also `i` start with a value of 0, and you do nums[i-1] which compare the first elemetn to the last one.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki that is mainly good advice if they were changing the order or length of the list they are modifying. There isn't anything wrong with updating a list in-place though, it can be very efficient or possibly even a requirement for very long lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your code:

- You loop `i` over `range(len(nums))`, so it starts at `0`, which means the first condition `nums[i] < nums[i-1]` evaluates to `nums[0] < nums[-1]` and I don't think you want to compare the first element to the last element at all.

For the rest, when you find an issue (i.e. `nums[i] < nums[i-1]`), you check if previous number could be lowered to sit between the current number and the number before the previous number, and then set it to the current number; if that doesn't work, you just lower the current number to be equal to the previous number and count either case.

You keep checking even if `count` is already 2 or greater though, which is very inefficient for long series. And since you increase `count` in either case, that increment could sit outside the conditional blocks.

So your code becomes:

```
nums = [-1,4,2,3]
count = 0
for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    if nums[i] < nums[i-1]:
        if (i == 1 or nums[i-2] <= nums[i]):
            nums[i-1] = nums[i]
        else:
            nums[i] = nums[i-1]
        if (count := count + 1) > 1:  # parentheses not needed, but for clarity
            break
            
print(count<=1)
```

Note that your solution will only work for max 1 flaw though. Turned into a function, consider this:

```
def almost_non_decreasing(nums, max_flaws=1):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] < nums[i - 1]:
            if (i == 1 or nums[i - 2] <= nums[i]):
                nums[i - 1] = nums[i]
            else:
                nums[i] = nums[i - 1]
            if (count := count + 1) > max_flaws:
                return False
    return True


print(almost_non_decreasing([-1, 4, 2, 3]))
print(almost_non_decreasing([5, 4, 2, 3]))
print(almost_non_decreasing([5, 4, 2, 3], 2))
```

The last one prints `False`, even though `[2, 2, 2, 3]` would work, but your solution will only try `[4, 4, 4, 3]` and then fail when it needs to change the final `3` as well.